# Delphi change text color for SysListView32 item of another window

Tags: delphi

how i change the text color of SysListView32 item in another application

The code below changing the text color of SysListView32 item in another application

```
procedure TMainForm.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ChangingTextColor([Here is the SysListView32 hwnd],22,RGB(0,0,0));
end;
```

The full procedure follows:

```
procedure ChangingTextColor(LVHandle: HWND; N: Integer;ClrCode:Integer);
var
  lvi: LV_ITEM;
  _lvi: PLVITEM;
  Item: array[0..1000] of char;
  _Item, _subitem: PChar;
  pid: Cardinal;
  process: THANDLE;
  writebytes,readbytes:ULONG_PTR;
begin
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(LVHandle, @pid);

  process := OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or PROCESS_VM_READ or PROCESS_VM_WRITE or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
  Win32Check(process<>0);
  try
    _lvi := PLVITEM(VirtualAllocEx(process, Nil, sizeof(TLVITEM), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
    Win32Check(_lvi<>nil);
    try
      _item := PChar(VirtualAllocEx(process, Nil, 512, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
      Win32Check(_item<>nil);
      try
        _subitem :=PChar(VirtualAllocEx(process, Nil, 512, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
        Win32Check(_subitem<>nil);
        try
          lvi.cchTextMax := 512;
          lvi.iSubItem := 0;
          lvi.pszText := '55';
          lvi.mask := LVIF_STATE;
          lvi.iItem := N;
          lvi.state := LVIS_FOCUSED or LVIS_SELECTED;
          lvi.stateMask := LVIS_FOCUSED or LVIS_SELECTED;

          Win32Check(WriteProcessMemory(process, _lvi, @lvi, sizeof(TLVITEM), writebytes));
          Win32Check(ReadProcessMemory(process, _item, @item, 512, readbytes));

          **SendMessage(LVHandle, LVM_SETTEXTCOLOR, LPARAM(_lvi), ClrCode);
          SendMessage(LVHandle, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);**

        finally
          Win32Check(VirtualFreeEx(process, _subitem, 0, MEM_RELEASE));
        end;
      finally
        Win32Check(VirtualFreeEx(process, _item, 0, MEM_RELEASE));
      end;
    finally
      Win32Check(VirtualFreeEx(process, _lvi, 0, MEM_RELEASE));
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(process);
  end;

end;
```

Question: Should the color (ClrCode) be integer or TColor ?

Comment: You can't just make up functionality of third party code. You have to read the documentation and heed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761208.aspx). `LVM_SETTEXTCOLOR` does not take a `LVITEM` as input, the `WParam` must be 0, so all of your virtual allocations are useless (not that they were correct to begin with):

```
procedure ChangingTextColor(LVHandle: HWND; ClrCode:Integer);
begin
    SendMessage(LVHandle, LVM_SETTEXTCOLOR, 0, ClrCode);
end;
```

In which case you can just use `ListView_SetTextColor()` instead:

```
ListView_SetTextColor(LVHandle, ClrCode);
```

You **cannot** set a per-item text color using the ListView API, there is no command for that purpose.  Per-item customizations require custom drawing by the ListView's owning application.  That is out of your control, unless you were to inject your own code into the other application and take control of the ListView's drawing by subclassing its drawing messages.

Comment: if i inject DLL into the traget process with this `procedure ChangingTextColor` it will work ?

Comment: `ListView_SetTextColor()` is just a wrapper for `SendMessage(LVM_SETTEXTCOLOR)`. Any window message that does not involve pointers will work just fine across process boundaries. The real question is, what does the receiving app do with the message when it is received. As long as the app lets the ListView process it normally, then it should work fine.